# remove child post from custom post type archive

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, conditional-tags

I have a custom post type and a page like this for displaying the posts inside :

**archive-(myCPT).php**
I've created 2 posts, and one of them is the child.
How can I display just the parent page inside my **archive-(myCPT).php**

Here is a snippet from **archive-(myCPT).php** :

```
<?php 

        if( have_posts() ){ 
            // normal blog layout
                $x = 1;
                while ( have_posts() ){
                    the_post(); 
                    get_template_part( 'inc/post-format/content-debate');
                    // advertising between posts
                    if($ad_posts_mode != 'none'){
                        // take into account ad frequency
                        if (($x % $ad_posts_frequency) == 0){

                            switch ($ad_posts_mode) {
                                case 'image':
                                    echo '<div class="'.(($ad_posts_box) ? 'box' : '').' between_posts"><a target="_blank" href="'.of_get_option('ad_posts_image_link').'"><img src="'.of_get_option('ad_posts_image').'"></a></div>';
                                break;
                                case 'html':
                                    echo '<div class="'.(($ad_posts_box) ? 'box' : '').' between_posts">'.apply_filters('shortcode_filter',do_shortcode(of_get_option('ad_posts_code'))).'</div>';
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $x++;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a post (of ony type) is a child, its property `post_parent` is a number with the parent’s post ID. Posts without a parent have a value `0` instead. So you can test this value:

```
if ( 0 === (int) $post->post_parent )
{
    // show the post
}
```

Another option is a filter on `pre_get_posts` (not tested, just an idea):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','hide_children' );

function hide_children( $query ) 
{
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', current_filter() );

    if ( is_admin() or ! $query->is_main_query() ) 
        return;

    if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive( 'your_post_type_name' ) )
        return;

    // only top level posts
    $query->set( 'post_parent', 0 );
}
```

Comment: I want to try the the first option , but I don't know where exactly should I put the if statement should I put it inside the `if( have_posts() ){` or ?

Comment: @Alecs Yes, use it _after_ calling `the_post();`.

Comment: I've added after post: like this `if ( 0 !== (int) $post->post_parent ) {
      get_template_part( 'inc/post-format/content-debate');
     }` but now is displaying just the child post

Comment: @Alecs Sorry, `0` must be the same. Fixed in my answer.